# Как сгруппировать данные по столбцу и вывести в файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код:

```
import requests

ips = ['129.203.29.198', '148.187.4.164','239.202.246.184','245.184.161.17','179.83.187.56','101.159.154.180','127.153.44.165',
'31.6.213.69','175.72.176.94','131.113.160.111','98.70.55.74']

for i in  ips:
    response = requests.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/' + i)
    country = (response.json().get('country_name'))
    i = list(i.split('\n'))
    country = list (country.split('\n'))
    print(country,'-', i)
```

Получаю ответ в следующем виде:

```
['United States'] - ['129.203.29.198']

['Switzerland'] - ['148.187.4.164']

[''] - ['239.202.246.184']

[''] - ['245.184.161.17']

['Brazil'] - ['179.83.187.56']

['China'] - ['101.159.154.180']

[''] - ['127.153.44.165']

['Poland'] - ['31.6.213.69']

['China'] - ['175.72.176.94']

['Japan'] - ['131.113.160.111']

['United States'] - ['98.70.55.74']
```

Как сгруппировать IP по странам и вывести в файл?

Так должно отображаться в ответе:

```
United States: 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3

China: 4.4.4.4, 5.5.5.5
```

Comment: Используйте dict. Кстати, вот эта строка country = list (country.split('\n')) формирует список стран. Как быть если там их вдруг окажется две?

Comment: ответ в json именно так выглядит? Решение задачи, первое значение определяем как наименование словаря, и добавляем в него элемент список, который дополняем при каждом проходе.

Comment: @Igor спасибо за совет, пробую его реализовать в коде, но толкового ничего не получается. Помогите, пожалуйста, написать решение. Спасибо.

Comment: ['United States'] - ['129.203.29.198'] - это строка или уже ваш вывод ?

Comment: @Igor это мой вывод

Comment: словарь = {}; 

страна = 'Brazil';

словарь[страна] = словарь[страна].append(ip);
# словарь[страна] = ['129.203.29.198', '98.70.55.74'] Разделил переносы строк точкой с запятой

Comment: если значения нет, то нужно обработать через if подставив страну без названия в качестве словаря. Итоговый словарь будет содержать все страны. Если завтра будет время напишу код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо всемм за помощь, доработал и все получилось

```
import requests
input_file = None
with open ('ips.txt', 'r') as input_ip:
    input_file = input_ip.read().split('\n')
    ips = list(input_file)
report = {}
for i in  ips:
    country = requests.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/' + i).json().get('country_name')
    country = country if country else 'Unknown_country'
    report.setdefault(country, list()).append(i)
key_country = report.keys()
with open('output.txt','w') as out:
    for i in key_country:
        ip = (report[i])
        str_ip = ', '.join(ip)
        out.write('{}: {}''\n'.format(i, str_ip))
        out.write('\n')
print ('Done!')
```

Answer (score 5):

Вот решение, которое использует Pandas модуль:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.DataFrame(ips, columns=['ip'])
df['country'] = df.ip.apply(lambda x: requests.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/' + x).json().get('country_name'))
grp = df.groupby('country').ip.apply(list)
```

return dictionary:

```
In [333]: grp.to_dict()
Out[333]:
{'': ['239.202.246.184', '245.184.161.17', '127.153.44.165'],
 'Brazil': ['179.83.187.56'],
 'China': ['101.159.154.180', '175.72.176.94'],
 'Japan': ['131.113.160.111'],
 'Poland': ['31.6.213.69'],
 'Switzerland': ['148.187.4.164'],
 'United States': ['129.203.29.198', '98.70.55.74']}
```

return JSON string:

```
In [332]: grp.to_json()
Out[332]: '{"":["239.202.246.184","245.184.161.17","127.153.44.165"],"Brazil":["179.83.187.56"],"China":["101.159.154.180","175.72.176.94"],"Japa
n":["131.113.160.111"],"Poland":["31.6.213.69"],"Switzerland":["148.187.4.164"],"United States":["129.203.29.198","98.70.55.74"]}'
```

или же просто записать в файл в указанном в вопросе формате:

```
(df.replace('', 'N/A')
   .groupby('country')
   .ip.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=','))
   .reset_index()
   .to_csv('d:/temp/out.txt', sep=':', index=None, header=None)
)
```

d:/temp/out.txt

```
Brazil:179.83.187.56
China:101.159.154.180,175.72.176.94
Japan:131.113.160.111
N/A:239.202.246.184,245.184.161.17,127.153.44.165
Poland:31.6.213.69
Switzerland:148.187.4.164
United States:129.203.29.198,98.70.55.74
```

**пошагово:**

```
In [315]: df = pd.DataFrame(ips, columns=['ip'])

In [316]: df
Out[316]:
                 ip
0    129.203.29.198
1     148.187.4.164
2   239.202.246.184
3    245.184.161.17
4     179.83.187.56
5   101.159.154.180
6    127.153.44.165
7       31.6.213.69
8     175.72.176.94
9   131.113.160.111
10      98.70.55.74

In [317]: df['country'] = df.ip.apply(lambda x: requests.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/' + x).json().get('country_name'))

In [318]: df
Out[318]:
                 ip        country
0    129.203.29.198  United States
1     148.187.4.164    Switzerland
2   239.202.246.184
3    245.184.161.17
4     179.83.187.56         Brazil
5   101.159.154.180          China
6    127.153.44.165
7       31.6.213.69         Poland
8     175.72.176.94          China
9   131.113.160.111          Japan
10      98.70.55.74  United States

In [320]: df.groupby('country').ip.apply(list)
Out[320]:
country
                 [239.202.246.184, 245.184.161.17, 127.153.44.165]
Brazil                                             [179.83.187.56]
China                             [101.159.154.180, 175.72.176.94]
Japan                                            [131.113.160.111]
Poland                                               [31.6.213.69]
Switzerland                                        [148.187.4.164]
United States                        [129.203.29.198, 98.70.55.74]
Name: ip, dtype: object

In [321]: df.groupby('country').ip.apply(list).to_json()
Out[321]: '{"":["239.202.246.184","245.184.161.17","127.153.44.165"],"Brazil":["179.83.187.56"],"China":["101.159.154.180","175.72.176.94"],"Japa
n":["131.113.160.111"],"Poland":["31.6.213.69"],"Switzerland":["148.187.4.164"],"United States":["129.203.29.198","98.70.55.74"]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы сгруппировать ip-адреса по странам, можно использовать [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections

# get countries corresponding to given ips
country2ips = collections.defaultdict(list)
for ip in input_ips:
    try:
        country2ips[reader.country(ip).country.name].append(ip)
    except geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError:
        country2ips['unknown'].append(ip)

# print ips grouped by countries
for country in sorted(country2ips):
    print("{}: {}".format(country, ', '.join(country2ips[country])))
```

где [`reader = geoip2.database.Reader('GeoLite2-Country.mmdb')`](https://geoip2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#geoip2-database-reader), использующий локальную копию [базы данных ip -> country](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb.gz), лицензированной под [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)

Чтобы сохранить результаты в файл, можно использовать перенаправление вывода при запуске скрипта: `python ip2country.py >result.txt` или передать параметр `file` в `print()` в примере кода выше.

Можно автоматически скачать `GeoLite2-Country.mmdb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import gzip
import hashlib
import os
import shutil
import urllib.request

import geoip2.database  # $ pip install geoip2

geolite_baseurl = 'http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/'

def download_geolite_database(filename):
    url = f'{geolite_baseurl}{filename}.gz'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, \
            gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response) as gzip_file, \
            open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(gzip_file, file)
    check_geolite_database_md5sum(filename)

def check_geolite_database_md5sum(filename):
    basename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    url = f'{geolite_baseurl}{basename}.md5'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        md5_hexdigest = response.read().decode()
    assert md5_hexdigest == md5sum(filename)

def md5sum(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        return hashlib.md5(file.read()).hexdigest()

filename = 'GeoLite2-Country.mmdb'
if not os.path.exists(filename):
    download_geolite_database(filename)

# get countries corresponding to given ips
with geoip2.database.Reader(filename) as reader:
    ...
```

Потестируйте, является ли качество предоставляемое geolite2 базой достаточным в вашем случае.